# How to implement GoogleSignIn

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, google-signin

Some of the docs [1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin) [2](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift) say I must use the `application:openURL:options:`. My question is -- since I'm already using that method, and the sample code for how to implement hijacks it entirely:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
  -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                            sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                            annotation: [:])
}
```

How can I identify that the openURL call is for signin?

What I would rather is to implement that method equivalent to how it is in FirebaseUI[3](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-ios/firebaseauthui/readme.md/):

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
  let sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String?
  if FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.handleOpen(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication) ?? false {
    return true
  }
  // other URL handling goes here.
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you might have noticed that `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle` method returns a `bool`, so you can call it like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
  -> Bool {
    if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication:options[.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: [:]) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

This approach is more useful in case your app supports other different kinds of logins (facebook, twitter etc.)
In that case, all you have to do is to add  more `if` conditions for each kind of urls.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Actually you don'y have to , you can chain them with `||` like this

```
public func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url as URL?, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) 
   || GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation)
   || FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.handleOpen(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication) ?? false

}
```

Anyone will hit will `return true` otherwise if all `false` then result will be `false`

Answer (score 2):

[According to the docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in.html#ac28f45cfd922f41bc35ba4c320f579e0) this method returns YES if GIDSignIn handled this URL.

So it seems that you can do exactly as what you do in the FUIAuth example, i.e. add an 'if' check on the return value:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    let isSignInHandled = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
        sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
        annotation: [:])
    if isSignInHandled {
        return true
    }
    // ... other code
}
```

Comment: Should be a comment

Comment: Why do you think so?